# How to fit intercept into particular value in ggplot linear model graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, intercept

I would like to generate a decomposition vs time graph using ggplot in R as following code :

```
ggplot(data=deco, aes(x = week, y = mass, group=interaction(treatment,habitat),
                      colour=habitat, linetype=treatment)) +   
 geom_point() +  
 theme_classic() + 
 geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=y~x)
```

Because the initial litter wight was 5 gram, so I expected that all the lines would start from 5 gram in the 0 week. However, I realized that all the lines have different starting points. I tried to find any solution to swift them all but all methods did not work well to me. Would be great if any of you could solve this.

[image: decomposition]

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: With a single group, you could do `formula = y ~ x + 0` and `method.args = list(offset = rep(5, nrow(data)))` But this will be difficult if your groups are different sizes---it's too bad `lm` won't recycle an offset of length 1. A straightforward workaround may be to transform the data so the intercept is `0` (i.e., subtract 5 from the response) and fit a model with no intercept. You could then use a transform on the y scale so the labeling is correct.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor, I ended up solving the issue by subtracting 5 from the response variable data.

Answer (score 2):

As Gregor indicated, this isn't trivial as group sizes are unknown and `geom_smooth` is a bit limited. There are two options, either fit your models outside `ggplot`. Or suppress the intercept, shift the y, and relabel your axis.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, drat, col = factor(am))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  xlim(0, 6)


Intercept <- 5
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, drat - Intercept, col = factor(am))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x + 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x + Intercept) +
  xlim(0, 6)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow - don't think I've seen anyone use `drat` as the response instead of `mpg`. But the scale works nicely for OP's example. (Nice demo of the method :)

Comment: I wanted something more close to the origin! :)